# javafx table row doesn't change color

Tags: css, javafx-2, tableview, tablerow, textcolor

In my program I have this on the css file:

```
.error-row {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

If the row in a table view is an error, it's text should be red. If is an error, I do `getStyleClass().add("error-row");` in the factory, but it doesn't work. If I add things like background color and font weight int the css `.error-row`, they work, but not the color. Anyone knows why?

Comment: have you tried `color: red` ?

Comment: normal css "commands" (I don't know how to call, sory) like that doesn't work since is javafx, but I tried anyway and didn't work.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the css class? Are you using a custom row factory, or a cell factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using a `rowFactory` on the `TableView`. The default css stylesheet defines the text fill on the table cell, which is a descendant of the table row, and so the default value overrides the value you set on the row.

Try

```
.error-row .table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that it was a `rowFactory` and not just a `cellFactory`. I'm new at JavaFX and didn't know about that. It worked, thank you for your help.